# Resolve Discord-Tag get Discord-ID programmatically

Tags: api, discord

I want to add a function to my userprofiles where users can enter their discord tag and if they do so, I want to resolve this to a link to their discordprofile so that users only have to click on the discordtag to open the profile in discord.

For that I need the ID. What Request do I need to send to the discord api in order to get the user ID for the entered tag?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that is impossible. The only way to get a user through Discord's API is through `/users/{user.id}`

Comment: Thats kinda bs from discord, if you already can search manually for them

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments with discord friend sending. I found out that you can actually obtain user the user ID by sending friend request.

Here's how:

1. Make a add request friend request to example#1234
2. Make another request to the relationship(AKA friend) list to get all pending "friends" with ID, username, avatar... This list actually contains all of the actual friends from the person that sent a friend request.
3. To find the requested username in the friend list, all you need is a loop searching for the corresponding username + discriminator.
4. Output the ID(if that's what you wanted), after the username and discriminator match.
5. Delete the pending request.

Here's a python script I wrote that will output the ID of the user with inputs of username, discriminator, and an user token(used for sending an authorized friend request):

```py
import requests
import json

# inputs
username = 'asdf'
discriminator = '1234'
TOKEN = 'ONLY USER TOKEN'

url = 'https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/relationships'

headers = {
    "authorization": TOKEN
}

# setting up a payload for sending friend request.
payload = {
    'username': username,
    'discriminator': discriminator
}

requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers) # step 1

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json() # step 2
if hasattr(result, 'message'):
    print('Invalid user token')
else:
    user_id = None

    for client in result: # step 3: a loop for finding the the username in the friend list
        if f'{client["user"]["username"]}#{client["user"]["discriminator"]}' == f'{username}#{discriminator}':
            user_id = client['id'] # step 4: save the user ID after finding it in the friend list
            break

    if user_id is None: # if no match is found then the user with that username and discriminator does not exist.
        print('user not found')
    else:
        url = f'https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/relationships/{user_id}'

        requests.delete(url, headers=headers) # step 5: delete the pending request

        print(user_id) # print out the user ID
```

And here's the data structure of the requested json from step 2:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "12345678901",
        "type": 1,
        "nickname": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "12345678901",
            "username": "example1",
            "avatar": "1234567890abcdef",
            "discriminator": "1234",
            "public_flags": 123
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "12345678902",
        "type": 1,
        "nickname": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "12345678902",
            "username": "example2",
            "avatar": "1234567890abcdef",
            "discriminator": "1234",
            "public_flags": 123
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "12345678903",
        "type": 1,
        "nickname": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "12345678903",
            "username": "example3",
            "avatar": "1234567890abcdef",
            "discriminator": "1234",
            "public_flags": 123
        }
    }
]
```

Downside:

You have to use an **user token** for sending the friend request.

## Updates:

10/4/2020: Added in error detection for invalid token and invalid username.