# User ID unique violation discord.js?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, bots, discord.js

Here is my code for the two functions I have coded.

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(hp, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = hp.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.health += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({
            user_id: id,
            health: amount
        });
        hp.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});
Reflect.defineProperty(hp, 'getHealth', {
    value: function getHealth(id) {
        const user = hp.get(id);
        return user ? user.health : 0;
    },
});
```

And when I try this:  `hp.add(message.author.id, 100);`, I get this error:

```js
errors: [
        ValidationErrorItem {
            message: 'user_id must be unique',
            type: 'unique violation',
            path: 'user_id',
            value: '648183573748121610',
            origin: 'DB',
            instance: [users],
            validatorKey: 'not_unique',
            validatorName: null,
            validatorArgs: []
        }
    ],
    fields: ['user_id'],
    parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id] {
        errno: 19,
        code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
        sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
    },
    original: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id] {
        errno: 19,
        code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
        sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
    },
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`balance`) VALUES ($1,$2);'
}
```

Could somebody tell me what is the problem? And also, could you please tell me the solution to the problem? More info: I'm creating a discord bot with discord.js. I am using Sequilize and SQLite to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting another user (Lioness100) on another question about ID's. It's actually not possible to get the ID of a discord user. You could make an array and then get the ID of a person you want, and then check from that array. But I think this image will resolve this question.

[Quote:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613091/resolve-discord-tag-get-discord-id-programmatically)
[image: ID]

Hoped this solved your question!